# Views global text area replacement patterns for multiple values

Tags: views

I have a views block that is listing the similar nodes (based on taxonomy terms).

I want to show some custom text and the taxonomy term field's value(s) on the footer of the block.

I added **Global: Text area** to footer of the views and selected the **Use replacement tokens from the first row option**.

What I want to show is that **My Term's other nodes** and I'm using that for what I wanted:

> [field_my_taxonomy_term]'s other nodes.

It works correctly if the field_my_taxonomy_term field has **only one** value but if it has multiple values (multiple terms) it only shows the first taxonomy term value.

### How can I show multiple values on Global: Text area?

---

This is the replacement patterns part of the Global: Text area:

- [title] == Content: Title
- [field_my_taxonomy_term] == Content: My Term
- %1 == Content: Nid title
- !1 == Content: Nid input
- %2 == Content: Has taxonomy term ID title
- !2 == Content: Has taxonomy term ID input

Comment: Any solution or opinion about that? I've been searching to find any solution but couldn't find yet.

Comment: The problem is solved by that way: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138682/other-related-nodes-with-the-same-taxonomy-block-grouping-problem - It's not the method I asked here but a better usage. If you have the same problem you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either display as a table, or change the settings to force fields to be included in the View.

When you add a field to Views, you can alter how it is represented, including Rewrite, Style and if it contains multiples, how to display those values.

Adjust the field settings for the field you want and then that should be represented in the replacement pattern further down the chain

Comment: The replacement tokens I used come from Contextual Filters, not from the fields area. So, there is no option as you said _(When you add a field to Views, you can alter how it is represented, including Rewrite, Style and if it contains multiples, how to display those values.)_

Comment: the field should still be included in the fields section, and then 'filtered' by the contextual filter to only show specific values. Then you would use the field as the replacement token, not the contextual filter itself