# Related Content Block with Tags

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have an interesting problem.
I try to build some kind of related content block.

Sortly, I use tags as a channels/catagories. For example; there is a content like best Spanish football clubs and this content got three tags; Barcelona, Real Madrid, Atl. Madrid.

For me, this three tags are channels and they got own pages. I try to find related channels with the best way.

I add a image and try to explain there. I give a example with three content.
That i need is last part of image, means counts of tags.
By this way i understand blue is most related with green.. after that yellow. Because many times they have taken place with together.

I am aware of this is unusual method and for this i cant answer anywhere.

Please help me, thanks :)

[image: example]

Comment: You can check this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138682/other-related-nodes-with-the-same-taxonomy-block-grouping-problem. Not 100% same but it gives an idea.

Comment: @herci thanks.. yes you are right it's a close example. I try over it but still cant resolve my problem.. Any other idea?